# Filter rows in a DataFrame by comparing with result of lookup in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have data about actual sales by sales person like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Salesperson id': [1, 2, 3, 4], "Q3 sales": [105, 82, 230, 58]})
   Salesperson id  Q3 sales
0               1       105
1               2        82
2               3       230
3               4        58
```

I also have their sales quotas like so:

```
quotas_df = pd.DataFrame({'Salesperson id': [1, 2, 3, 4], "Quota": [88, 95, 200, 65]})
quotas_df = quotas_df.set_index('Salesperson id')

                Quota:
Salesperson id        
1                   88
2                   95
3                  200
4                   65
```

I'd like to get a subset of `df` with only the rows where the sales person has exceeded their sales quota. I try the following:

```
filtered_df = df[(df['Q3 sales'] > quotas_df.loc[df['Salesperson id']]['Quota'])]
```

This fails with:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Any pointers for the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the error because the two DataFrames' indexes are not aligned.

```
(
    df.set_index('Salesperson id')
    .loc[lambda x: x['Q3 sales'] > quotas_df['Quota']]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Salesperson id': [1, 2, 3, 4], "Q3 sales": [105, 82, 230, 58]})

quotas_df = pd.DataFrame({'Salesperson id': [1, 2, 3, 4], "Quota": [88, 95, 200, 65]})


s = df['Salesperson id'].map(quotas_df.set_index('Salesperson id')['Quota']))
filtered_df = df[(df['Q3 sales'] > s]
print (filtered_df)
   Salesperson id  Q3 sales
0               1       105
2               3       230
```

Answer (score 1):

You could merge the two dataframes and then filter normally:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Salesperson id': [1, 2, 3, 4], "Q3 sales": [105, 82, 230, 58]})
quotas_df = pd.DataFrame({'Salesperson id': [1, 2, 3, 4], "Quota": [88, 95, 200, 65]})

filtered_df = df.merge(quotas_df, on='Salesperson id')
filtered_df[filtered_df['Q3 sales'] > filtered_df['Quota']]
```

Output:

```
   Salesperson id  Q3 sales  Quota
0               1       105     88
2               3       230    200
```